# Directive in Angular not getting DATA

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

My directive is not getting any data. In console i get that total items: undefined. It's all the same even if i'm passing a number or a value from my controller. Nor do i get any values at my template URL. Thank you in advance.

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('adminApp')
        .directive('pagination', paginate);

    function paginate() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                totalItems:  '=',
                itemsOnPage: '=',
                pageUrl:         '=',
                currentPage: '='

            },
            templateUrl: 'assets/js/admin/templates/pagination-template.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                console.log("Total Items: ",scope.totalItems);
            },
        };
    }
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="vm.promiseReady">
    <div pagination totalItems="300" pageUrl="vm.pageUrl" currentPage="vm.currentPage"></div>
</div>
```

HTML TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="pagination">
<div class="pagination-bttns">
    <a class="pagination-bttn"
       href="#"
       ng-if="currentPage != 1"
       ng-href="{{pageUrl}}{{currentPage-1}}"
    >
    PREVIOUS {{totalItems}}
    </a>

    <a class="pagination-bttn"
       href="#"
       ng-if="currentPage != totalItems"
       ng-href="{{pageUrl}}/{{currentPage+1}}"
    >
    NEXT
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on directives, in the section titled "Normalization".

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

Try swapping

```
<div pagination totalItems="300" pageUrl="vm.pageUrl" currentPage="vm.currentPage"></div>
```

to (Notice the [dash-delimited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Computers) attributes now)

```
<div pagination total-items="300" page-url="vm.pageUrl" current-page="vm.currentPage"></div>
```

This is because, as the documentation says, all HTML attributes must be dash-delimited instead of camelCase.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Nemanja swapping to dash-delimited fix it? If so, I can remove the second suggestion.

Comment: Yes, only the first part did it for me. The value of 300 still passes even though i left the '='.

Comment: @Nemanja If this helped you solve your problem, please consider selecting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Html change `totalItems` to total-items and other attributes similarly. Angular Directive will change hash separated texts to camelcase in scope objects. So, your new Html should be:

```
<div ng-if="vm.promiseReady">
    <div pagination total-items="300" page-url="vm.pageUrl" current-page="vm.currentPage"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The scope on the directive is expecting a variable to bind with.  You have simply added an attribute value.  Something like this will fix it.

```
<div ng-if="vm.promiseReady">
    <div pagination ng-init="vm.totalItems=300" total-items="vm.totalItems" pageUrl="vm.pageUrl" currentPage="vm.currentPage"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-if="vm.promiseReady">
    <div pagination total-items="300" pageUrl="vm.pageUrl" currentPage="vm.currentPage"></div>
</div>

     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.totalItems = parseInt(attrs.totalItems);
            console.log("Total Items: ",scope.totalItems);
        },
```

In the latter case I would probably remove totalItems off the public scope for the directive though.